# display:inline-block and pseudo-element to do Vertically placed

Tags: html, css

I'm using `display:inline-block` and pseudo-element(`::before`, `::after`) to do [`vertically`-`middle`]
but it's not working, pseudo-element will occupy a row
even it `width` is `0`, I don't know why?

I know other methods to do it(likes `flex`, `position`, `line-height`...)
I just curious, what's wrong in this?
Thank you everyone. Demo below or here : https://jsfiddle.net/pm06tkjs/

```css
.container{
  height: 200px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.container::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.img-group {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

img {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  max-width: 20%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="img-group">
    <img src="https://www.penghu-nsa.gov.tw/FileDownload/Album/Big/20161012162551758864338.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://www.penghu-nsa.gov.tw/FileDownload/Album/Big/20161012162551758864338.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://www.penghu-nsa.gov.tw/FileDownload/Album/Big/20161012162551758864338.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://www.penghu-nsa.gov.tw/FileDownload/Album/Big/20161012162551758864338.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://www.penghu-nsa.gov.tw/FileDownload/Album/Big/20161012162551758864338.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why do you add before after for this simple task. you easily align it middle with little css without using all this css

Comment: yes, I know, I just curious and want to learn
Thanks your comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

default margin between your inline element is the problem! for solving it add `font-size:0` for your inline element parent.

```css
.container{
  height: 200px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  font-size:0;
}

.container::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.img-group {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size:0;
}

img {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 20%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="img-group">
    <img src="https://www.penghu-nsa.gov.tw/FileDownload/Album/Big/20161012162551758864338.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://www.penghu-nsa.gov.tw/FileDownload/Album/Big/20161012162551758864338.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://www.penghu-nsa.gov.tw/FileDownload/Album/Big/20161012162551758864338.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://www.penghu-nsa.gov.tw/FileDownload/Album/Big/20161012162551758864338.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://www.penghu-nsa.gov.tw/FileDownload/Album/Big/20161012162551758864338.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

for more detail for how to remove gap between inline elements check [here](https://teamtreehouse.com/library/removing-gaps-between-inline-and-inlineblock-elements)

Comment: wow!! actually solving it by [font-size]
I'm learing a new knowledge!
Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 1**: You Can set the width of img-group less than 100% percentage.

```css
.container{
      height: 200px;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }

    .container::before {
      content: '';
      display: inline-block;
      width: 0;
      height: 100%;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }


.img-group {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 99%;
}

img {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  max-width: 20%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="img-group">
        <img src="https://www.penghu-nsa.gov.tw/FileDownload/Album/Big/20161012162551758864338.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="https://www.penghu-nsa.gov.tw/FileDownload/Album/Big/20161012162551758864338.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="https://www.penghu-nsa.gov.tw/FileDownload/Album/Big/20161012162551758864338.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="https://www.penghu-nsa.gov.tw/FileDownload/Album/Big/20161012162551758864338.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="https://www.penghu-nsa.gov.tw/FileDownload/Album/Big/20161012162551758864338.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
```

**Approch 2**: You are using display inline block property and on image margin right also. So display inline block also takes some extra space around the image block. So you can add width 100% if you want to and also add the margin left in negative.

```css
.container{
      height: 200px;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }

    .container::before {
      content: '';
      display: inline-block;
      width: 0;
      height: 100%;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .img-group {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: -4px;
    }

    img {
      display: inline-block;
      margin-right: -4px;
      max-width: 20%;
      height: auto;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="img-group">
        <img src="https://www.penghu-nsa.gov.tw/FileDownload/Album/Big/20161012162551758864338.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="https://www.penghu-nsa.gov.tw/FileDownload/Album/Big/20161012162551758864338.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="https://www.penghu-nsa.gov.tw/FileDownload/Album/Big/20161012162551758864338.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="https://www.penghu-nsa.gov.tw/FileDownload/Album/Big/20161012162551758864338.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="https://www.penghu-nsa.gov.tw/FileDownload/Album/Big/20161012162551758864338.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Oh, I see where the trouble!! is margin~~
the answer is pretty too,
I hope I can accept all answer, Thank you!!

Comment: @lynn No problem...Thanks you are noticed my answer